# individual plots working fine but par(new=T) to put the two together displays incorret graph

Tags: r, par

i m new to R and i m still following some basic tutorials but i decided to practice what i learned with some of my own data and i m getting some wierd results. the individual plots work fine, but when i put the two together the line goes from the lowest to highest value on the first plot instead of the second, contrary to what happens when i run the plots individually. would appreciate any help.
code as follows:

```
library(datasets)
library(plotrix)
y<- c(cfa1$X7d,cfa1$X15d) ; y
x<- c(7,7,7,15,15,15) ; x
plot(x,y )
par(new=T)
mean7 <- mean(cfa1$X7d) ; mean7
media15 <- mean(cfa1$X15d); media15

plot(c(7,15),c(mean7,media15),ann=F, axes=F, type="l" )
```

(x7d and x15d are 2 colums with 3 values each, at 7 and 15 days respectively, which i imported from a csv cfa1)

for reproducibility as requested:

```
 > dput(cfa1[c("X7d", "X15d")])
 structure(list(X7d = c(136.7, 84.6, 158), X15d = c(478.1, 135.5, 
 108.6)), .Names = c("X7d", "X15d"), row.names = c("1c", "2c", 
 "3c"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you edit the results of  `dput(cfa1[c("X7d", "X15d")])` into your question so we can fully reproduce your problem? `dput` makes copy/pasteable input out of R objects.

Comment: sure thing,hope this is the result you whanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `par(new = TRUE)` for this - it is a rarely used special command where the next plotting command draws the new stuff "*as if it were on a new plot*", but not on a new plot. No values from the previous plot are remembered. You can make it work *if you set the x and y limits to be the same*, but there's an easier way.

The more common way to *add* a line to an existing plot is the `lines()` command (use `points()` for points). They will *add* to the existing plot by default:

```
plot(x, y)
lines(c(7, 15), c(mean7, media15))
```

The above is also nice because `lines` won't re-label the axes or anything.

[image]

The alternative, using `new = TRUE` and specifying axis limits:

```
xlim = range(x)
ylim = range(y)
plot(x, y, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(c(7, 15), c(mean7, media15), type = "l",
         ann = F, axes = F, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
```

This also creates the plot above, but it is a lot more of a hassle.

Comment: that solved it, and very good info to have, thanks very much !